# PHP Call protected method as public from child context

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I've just written the following code (expecting it to fail) and I can't really understand why does this behave like this:

```
<?php
abstract class Test1 {
    protected function methodTest1() {}
}

class Test2 extends Test1{
    public function methodTest2() {
        $test3 = new Test3();
        $test3->methodTest1();
    }
}

class Test3 extends Test1 {
}

$test2 = new Test2();
$test2->methodTest2();
```

Expected result: Fatal Error since I am calling a "protected" member of a class, just like it would be a public member

Actual result: ... works

Am I missing something?

I assume it has something to do with the fact that Test2 extends Test1 so it has access to it, but it doesn't make sense in this case since I am not calling "test1()" from Test2 but from Test3 context. So this means "Test3" is a brand new instance which basically doesn't expose any methods. From my point of view, this code works with 2 completely different instances of 2 objects

Even the IDE (PHPStorm) says it is OK.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct behavior. Visibility has to do with class it is not constrained to objects (class instances). So this makes sense:

```
class Foo {

    private $field;

    public function method(Foo $fooInstance) {
        //have access to everything from $fooInstance
        //cause I'm already in that class
        $fooInstance->field;
    }

}
```

For protected members you'll have access if you're using and in any of the child classes etc.

Comment: I understand that of course. My concern / issue was that from my POV, creating a new object, would basically mean that I am working with a new instance, thus all the standard rules apply. However, reading from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php section "Visibility from other objects" seems it is not the case. Which is  a bit strange, don't you (partially at least) agree?

Comment: in your example within method2 $test3 and $this are the same type (Test1), so why wouldn't you have access?

Comment: The type is the same yes. However, the instances are not. I understand the fact that PHP OOP visibility works as you said. At least from a logical POV it doesn't make sense (?). The type clearly says the method is protected so it cannot be accessed as public. In my mind that means that absolutely anywhere I do a new Test3, I won't have access to any methods (since there are no public methods).

Comment: Well not from "absolutely anywhere" right? Clearly if you're coding something within the block that defines Test3 you have access not only to protected but to private as well. Consider private visibility for a sec. The trick is to think Test3 objects you're working with from within Test3 are "coming home" so to speak. They are completely exposed once accessed from within the Test3 block. But that's ok cause you're still in Test3 block, so whatever you do others wont break encapsulation cause you already know it. Dont know how to explain it better.

Comment: Protected is similar just it includes this sort of freedom to child objects as well.

Comment: I sort of get it (at least better than my initial WTF moment). Although it still breaks my mind a bit regarding encapsulation. From what I understand it's fine since they are in the same context / building block thus its still encapsulated. I don't fully agree with this but at least now it makes sense on the "WHY" part hah. Thanks for the answer(s) !

Comment: I agree about that when it comes to protected methods. Encapsulation is stretched in that case and I don't like using them. That's why I was using private to illustrate the visibility. When it comes to private access encapsulation is preserved, it is all in one block (file), easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Protected variables are accessible both within the current class, and any sub-classes (i.e. any classes that extend that class).

Given that you are extending Test1 in both Test2 and Test3, the protected function methodTest1() is accessible in both cases.

If you changed methodTest1() from protected to private, it would then become inaccessible to Test2 and Test3.

The fact that Test3 is being called from within Test2 is irrelevant - both classes extend Test1, and therefore both classes have access to methodTest1().

Comment: I understand that of course. My concern / issue was that from my POV, doing a new object, would basically mean that I am working with a new instance, thus all the standard rules apply. [EDIT] found the link also from php.net on OOP visiblity and seems to also state that. A bit weird from my POV but meh. Thanks for the answer.